# How to get os locale from flex 4 application?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, locale, flash

Does anyone know how I can get operating system locale name from my flex 4 application?
I'm just interested in any information about locale.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

I think you may want [Capabilities.language](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#language).

Answer (score 0):

You should use Capabilities.languages[0] as it's explained in Adobe Documentation.

**Only available on Air runtime.**

Comment: This is only available on Air runtime. That's probably what I've missed.